# Inconsistency while fitting data using lmfit and scipy.optimize

Tags: model-fitting, lmfit, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to fit my data to a model using lmfit library as well as scipy.optimize library. For both libraries, i am using the minimize function and using the Powell method. But, my fits for both of them are coming slightly different. Could anyone please explain why that inconsistency is there?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no one can possibly explain why they are inconsistent.  If you posted minimal example code and the output results then it might be possible that someone could explain the difference, and perhaps even help you decide whether they are in fact inconsistent.  Cheers.